# Can't get Mixed Reality Controllers To Initiate Movement Forward or Any Direction

Tags: aframe

I'm trying to move with the controller in my scene when I open my view in internet explorer. I can't seem to get the code right to enable the movement for the windows mixed reality controller.
`

```
<!-- Player -->
<a-entity hand-controls="left"></a-entity>
<a-entity hand-controls="right"></a-entity>

<a-entity windows-motion-controls="hand: left"></a-entity>
<a-entity windows-motion-controls="hand: right"></a-entity>

<a-entity id="rig"
          movement-controls
          position="6 0 11">
<a-entity camera
          position="0 1.4 0"
          look-controls="pointerLockEnabled: true"></a-entity>
</a-entity>
```

`
When I push the controller forward and step into mixed reality I don't actually move forward into the scene.

Comment: Can you share a runnable sample on https://glitch.com/~aframe ?

Comment: So I think I was using the joystick when it actually wants to use the touchpad to navigate. So I can move forward, I was just not using the right bound control.